# Delphi $Message directive based on condition

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to generate a fatal compiler error using the `{$Message Fatal ''}` directive, but based on a field value.  For example:

```
if FIsFileListMode=false then
begin
  {$Message Fatal 'Use SwitchToFileListMode before use FillDir.'}
  exit;
end;
```

But this is not working.

Have I made an error in the code?  Or is there a better way to use a conditional message directive?

Comment: FWIW it is not idiom to test against True and False. Instead write if bool or if not bool.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a Pascal `if` because the compiler still *compiles* all branches. Instead you have to use a conditional directive such as `{$IF}`.

Of course this implies that the condition is evaluated by the compiler and not at runtime. But that's hardly surprising if you wish to generate a compile time error.

I have assumed that the boolean you test is a constant because that's the only thing that makes sense when emitting compiler errors. But if that boolean is a variable then the entire question makes no sense. A variable has value that is known only during execution. And compiler errors require the value to be known during compilation.

Comment: And if you use `{$IF}` to check a value, it must be a constant value, not a variable, so it can be evaluated at compile-time instead of run-time.

Comment: I didn't state that explicitly since it seemed so obvious. If the asker wants a compile time error then surely they realise that the boolean must be constant.

Answer (score 4):

The field you are testing is subject to change at *run-time*.

Compiler messages are generated at *compile-time*.  There is no way to generate a compile-time error message based on run-time conditions.

You have two options:

1. Use an `ASSERT()` to check the field value at runtime and raise an exception if this condition is found to have been violated.
2. Replace the field with a symbol that can be set and tested using compiler directives.

Of the two I strongly suspect that the assertion is the most appropriate approach in your case but for completeness here are the two approaches and the differences between them.

### The ASSERT Approach

Both your `if` statement and the need to call `EXIT` are combined into a single `ASSERT()` call:

```
 ASSERT(fIsFileListMode, 'Use SwitchToFileListMode before using FillDir');
```

This ensures that if it is possible to change the value of the field at runtime to allow `FillDir` to be called then as long as the necessary runtime conditions are met *at the point that FillDir is called* then the call will succeed.

Otherwise the assertion failure will alert the developer (or if you are careless, the user) to the mistake.

### The Compiler Symbols Approach

Either using a project setting or some conditional compilation in your unit or a suitable include file, define a `FILELISTMODE` symbol.

Your `if` statement is then replaced by a test for this symbol having been defined, but there is still no need to call `EXIT` since compilation will simply fail immediately if the symbol is not defined:

```
{$ifNdef FILELISTMODE}
  {$message FATAL 'Must $define FILELISTMODE in order to use FillDir'};
{$endif}
```

The key thing to understand here is that the evaluation of compiler directives has nothing what-so-ever to do with the flow of control in the run-time code.  The two things are evaluated at entirely different points in time and with entirely different contexts.

Your runtime code has no way to directly inspect the "value" of any compiler symbols and the compiler has no way to access fields or variables (though it can test *constants* to a limited extent since constant values are also defined and therefore available at compile-time).

Comment: FIsFileListMode could be a true constant

Comment: And it's usually more readable to use $IF than $IFDEF. So your option 2 introduces complexity where none is needed.

Comment: Really ?  You consider `$if not defined(FILELISTMODE)` less complex than `ifndef FILELISTMODE` ?  Four (4) syntactic elements to remember (and not make mistakes with) versus just two (2).  Or put another way: **TRIPLE** the number of *arguments*.  The directive parser will not report any mistakes.  eg. **$if NOT FILELISTMODE** compiles and it will work *if* you are using a true constant, but will not error if no such constant exists.  And if you mistakenly *think* this will react to a compiler symbol, it just doesn't work.  With `ifdef/ifndef` it's *only* the symbol you have to get right.

Comment: You see how many things you need to consider with your "simpler" suggestion ? You personally may find it more "readable" (largely subjective) but to conflate that with reducing complexity is demonstrably and absurdly false in this case.  ;)

Comment: I'm talking about `{$IF SomeConstantBool}`. I don't think my understanding is mistaken here. It's clearly simpler this way for the code in the question since the asker is not using conditional symbols. Perhaps time to cool off a little!

Comment: Message directive doc: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/MESSAGE_directive_(Delphi)